# Why am I getting a response code of 404 when I can load the page manually without any issues?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import requests
import click
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    webpage = requests.get(url)
    reqStatus = webpage.status_code
    DecodeURL = (webpage.content.decode())
    if reqStatus != 200:
        print(url)
        print(f'HTTP response code: {reqStatus}. Not 200. Exiting script.')
        exit(1)
    return DecodeURL

def get_links(url):
    html = get_html(url)
    CodeU = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    all_links = CodeU.findAll('a')
    checkurl = url 
    with open('crawl.txt', 'a') as wr:
        for link in all_links:
            wr.write(str(link.get('href')))
            wr.write('\n')
    with open('crawl.txt', 'r') as r:
        pattern = re.findall(r'\b'+checkurl+r'.*', r.read())
    with open('crawl.txt', 'w') as w:
        for line in pattern:
            checkline = line.rstrip()
            removechar = checkline.rstrip('/') 
            if removechar != checkurl:
                w.write(line)
                w.write('\n')
    with open('crawl.txt', 'r') as r:
        lines = r.readlines()
        newlines = []
        for line in lines:
            if line not in newlines and line != line+'/':
                newlines.append(line)
    with open('crawl.txt', 'w') as w:
        for line in newlines:
            w.write(line)

@click.command()                                                                                                                    
@click.option('--url', '-u', prompt='Web URL', help='URL of webpage to extract from.')
@click.option('--crawldepth', '-c', default=0, help='If links are found, how many to scan 
through?')

def main(url, crawldepth):
    get_html(url)
    get_links(url)
    if int(crawldepth) == 0:
        exit(0)
    with open('crawl.txt', 'r') as r:
        n = 1
        crawllist = r.readlines()
        for line in crawllist:
            URL = line
            try:
                iterations(URL, crawldepth)
            except SystemExit:
                pass
            n = n + 1
            if n > int(crawldepth):
                exit(0)

def iterations(URL, crawldepth):
    url = URL
    get_html(url)
    get_links(url)

if __name__=='__main__':
        main()
```

My goal here is to check a webpage for all its links that match to the initial 'url' input by user. All of these links are then written to a file called 'crawl.txt'. I want to be able to go a certain depth equal to 'crawldepth'. For example, if crawldepth = 1, the functions 'get_html' and 'get_links' are called twice(once with 'main', once with 'iteraitons'), and the first line of crawl.txt is read as the new 'url'. Crawl.txt is ammended with more links. The 'error' I receive is built into 'get_html'; if the response code is NOT equal to 200, the url variable is printed, and the actual response code is printed as well. Then the code exits with 1. This is expected IF the URL isn't giving a code 200.

Here in lies the problem. Using the example above, I get a 404 code when 'crawldepth' is > 0 and running through a second time. BUT when python prints the url to terminal, it is the first line of crawl.txt. If I search that url manually i.e. entered into my webbrowser, the page loads up without any issues. I am baffled by this.

I expect the code response to be 200 since when I search it manually, thats what I get. But this clearly is not the case when running the code. I don't get any errors from python. It seems like it runs error free.

I am AWARE that there is an issue with how I am filtering the links in 'get_links'. The second run of code if crawldepth > 0 will often give me an empty crawl.txt. This might throw an error if int(crawldepth) > number of lines in crawl.txt. This is what I will be working on next.

I've tried the following:

- enter the first line of crawl.txt when first running the script: it runs successfully.
- placing 'print(url') before the exit code if statement. I get the FIRST url entered when setting the options via terminal, then the second url, which is actually the first line of crawl.txt. But this is where the script exits as explained above.

To summarize, if I run the code with crawldepth = 0, I get no issues. It's ONLY when crawldepth > 0, and after the first run through. So basically, if crawldepth is >0, the function 'iterations' gets called, then 'get_html' exits the code with printing the 'url' and the response code.

I'm running the code with './' in terminal. Everything is updated and upgraded.

Comment: Can you share the url with us?

Comment: https://github.com

Comment: You aren't stripping the newlines off of the lines read from your file, making them invalid URLs.

Comment: @jasonharper you answered the question. Not sure how to mark your comment as an answer though.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your code, from a quick scan over.
For instance, you are using deprecated syntax: `findAll` should be `find_all`.
Probably the main issue is the fact you are not giving `requests` a proper `header` containing a valid `user-agent`. Something like this:

```
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get(<your_url>, headers=headers)
```

More, if you plan on scraping multiple pages on the same website, you should use `requests.Session()`.

Requests documentation can be found here: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/